# How To Insert Parenthesis In An Infix Expression Using Stack

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, prefix, infix-notation

I need an algorithm to insert parenthesis in an *infix* expression using **stack**.
for example:

> input : 12/c+c*p^(8+9)
>
> output : ((12/c)+(c*(p^(8+9))))

I just need the algorithm for this and it is ok if we reach the output through *prefix* or *postfix*. but the **output should be exact as the example.** an infix expression with full parenthesis.

I'll appreciate if someone can give a pseudocode or step by step example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this before by means of reverse polish notation (RPN). First you need to construct a postfix version of the expression. You could use [the shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail). Secondly, you need to "evaluate" (symbolically) the postfix expression you just created. [The RPN evaluation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) does this.

Answer (score 0):

1 - convert to postfix

2 - read the postfix expression

3 - a loop on postfix expression ... if character is operand push in stack else if operator ... pop top two in the stack and insert this two with the operator that is current character in the parentheses and push it in stack again